# Form selection handling

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a product selection page where you choose a plan and once selected it displays the selection information in a div. The problem is if the page gets refreshed the summary div disappears but it remembers your form selection. How can I get it so it still remembers the summary as well?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("div.plan").hide();

      $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
          $("div.plan").hide();
          $("div[planid=" + $(this).val() +"]").show();
      });
});
</script>

<input type="radio" name="plan" value="1" /> Plan 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="plan" value="2" /> Plan 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="plan" value="3" /> Plan 3 <br />

<div class="plan" planid="1">Plan 1 details</div>
<div class="plan" planid="2">Plan 2 details</div>
<div class="plan" planid="3">Plan 3 details</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your code abode, you can trigger the `click` handler on the selected radio button, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.plan").hide();

  $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
      $("div.plan").hide();
      $("div[planid=" + $(this).val() +"]").show();
  }).filter(':checked').click();
});
```

What this does is uses the handler you're already binding, then from those elements gets the `:checked` one and executes the `click` event handler, showing the proper `<div>`.

As an aside, `planid` isn't a valid attribute, if you're doing down this road go ahead and use [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) so you'll be HTML5 valid as you go (they present no problems in HTML4).

Comment: thankyou that worked perfectly and thanks for the heads up on the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a URL hash to maintain state.

When the selection is made, do something like this:

```
document.location = document.location + "#P1"
```

When the page reloads, look for the hash in the URL and parse what's on the other side.

"#P1" (1=plan 1, 2=plan 2 etc.)

Then adjust your display accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:radio:checked').each(function(){
    $('div[planid=' + $(this).val + ']').show();
  });
});
```

Note that there may be a flash on page load without the summary being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled with pure CSS.

Give your radio buttons some classes (plan-1, plan-2, plan-3, etc) and give your `div.plan` elements some classes to match (plan-1, plan-2, plan-3, etc; using the same class name is fine):

```
.plan {
  display: none;
}

.plan-1:checked ~ .plan-1,
.plan-2:checked ~ .plan-2,
.plan-3:checked ~ .plan-3 {
  display: block;
}
```

of course, this requires CSS3 selectors, javascript can handle the backwards-compatibility. Using the `:checked` selector in CSS can allow you to create pure-css toggle menus, along with pure-css accordion effects.